# Total number of unique n-element sets from a base of unique elements

Tags: combinatorics

I have searched for the answer for this on the site (and on the Internet) and have not found the answer. I do apologize if this is answered and I do not have the vocabulary to ask or search for the question properly.

I am trying to determine a mathematical method for determining how many unique n-element sets can be made from a base group of elements when each element can be used only once per set.

For instance, take the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

0, 1, and 21 are invalid because they are not complete sets.

012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 023, 024, 025, 026, etc. are all valid.

020 is not because it uses element 0 twice.

Given the valid sets above:
  021, 102, 210 are invalid (duplicates) because they use the same elements as 012.

I have determined by brute force that the answer to this for 3 element sets out of 7 unique elements is 35.

012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 023, 024, 025, 026, 034, 035, 036, 045, 046, 056, 123, 124, 125, 126, 134, 135, 136, 145, 146, 156, 234, 235, 236, 245, 246, 256, 345, 346, 356, 456

For 3 element sets out of 5 unique elements (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) is 10.

012, 013, 014, 023, 024, 034, 123, 124, 134, 234

I would like to be able to calculate the answer to this problem for any combination of base elements, and n-element sets. Using the brute force approach I am using would be impractical for large sets from very large numbers of elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of $k$-element subsets of an $n$-element set is often denoted by $\binom{n}{k}$.   There are other notations for the same numbers, for example ${}^nC_k$, and variants. One formula for $\binom{n}{k}$ is 
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}.$$
Here $m!$  denotes the product of all the integers from $m$ down to $1$. So for example $5!=5\cdot 4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1=120$.

**Example:** We do the calculation for the number of ways to choose $3$ objects from $7$. By definition, this is $\binom{7}{3}$, which is $\frac{7!}{3!4!}$. We could calculate $7!$ (it is $5040$), but there is a shortcut.

Note that $7!=7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4!$. Thus $\frac{7!}{3!4!}=\frac{7\cdot 6\cdot 5\cdot 4!}{3!4!}$. By cancellation, this is $\frac{7\cdot 6\cdot 5}{3!}$. But $3!=6$, so we get $35$.

For more information, please google **Binomial Coefficients**, and **Pascal Triangle**. Wikipedia has good writeups.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will give this a look. I'm not seeing where m/m! is coming from (or what the ! in the formula denotes for that matter), but that I am sure is my fault for not having enough math skill to get this in the first place (first year college algebra). I guess it was wishful thinking to believe that it would be something simple where I plug in 7 and 3 and do a couple operations and end up with 35. At least that does not jump out at me.

Comment: I will add the calculation in the answer, since writing math in comments is more awkward.

Comment: I had not encountered the '!' symbol in mathematics before so I had looked that up. Good to have one more tool in my maths-bag. That and your example solved it for me. Thank you so much!

Comment: Also, thank you for the references to Binomial Coefficients and Pascal Triangle. These are both interesting reads. Another step forward in knowledge, another step forward in skill!

Comment: You are welcome. Your comment reminded me to do what I should have done already, which is to do at least one explicit computation.